# Android Studio Device File Explorer run-as:Package 'my project name' is unknown

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio 3.0 and I want to access a sqlite db, so I want to download the db inside `data/data/project`, but when I connect an android phone and open project folder then this happen, `run-as: Package 'my project' is unknown`.

**Device's package directory on real device:**

[image]

But when I use the emulator to do this, everything is fine.

Does anyone know why is it?

**Device's package directory on emulator:**

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For security reason, it's not allowed.
You can do it only on emulator or rooted device.

But you can add needed files in assets, so these are included in APK.

build.gradle:

```
android {
  sourceSets.main {
    assets.srcDir '/absolute/path/to/your/assets/folder'
  }
}
```